# I am getting confused why it is printing printf statement by putting printf(A-9)

Tags: c, pointers, printf, character

**here is my simple code you can take a look**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("PanditJI");
    char *A = "SuhanaMausam";
    printf(A);
    printf(A-9);    
}
```

why printf(A-9) printing the previous statement again?

Here is the output of the code:

[image]

Comment: It's **Undefined Behaviour**. You were unlucky some thing you recognized got printed, your program could as well just do nothing, or crash, or start WWIII, ... `A - 9` calculates an invalid address (an address pointing outside the reserved memory for `A`) and then `printf()` (tries to) use that address for printing a string.

Comment: Also note your compiler issued a couple **warnings** (not errors). Basically a warning notifies you about some legal but unusual and possibly unwanted construct. In your case `char foo[] = "bar"; printf("%s", foo) /*usual*/` vs `printf(foo) /*unusual*/`

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: it is undefined behaviour (as pmg already commented)

Long Answer: You need to know where the literals are stored in your executable!
You didn't provide any details on what operating system you are using, but the Windows PE Executable File Format is in my opinion perfect to give examples.
In Windows you Executable consists of a header and many sections. Typical sections are `.data`, `.rdata`, `.bss` and `.text`. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) is the reference from the windows docs. All those sections have a meaning:

- The stuff in the `.text` section contains the machine code.
- The `.bss` section contains uninitialized data (static variables).
- The `.data` section contains initialized data
- And for your case `.rdata` contains read only data, like strings in C

In other words: you cannot edit your strings, unless you store them in an array.
Now for the details (still simplified): Your compiler places a hint to the linker in the compiled object/output files of where the literals in question shall be stored. Your linker will then collect all the literals and place them into the section the compiler wants them to be in. Again: Strings are read only, so they will be in the `.rdata` section.
The literal `"PanditJI"` is exactly 9 characters long. 8 visible and a nul character `\0` to indicate the end of the string. ("SuhanaMausam" is 13 characters long).

They will be packed into the executable the most compact way to store space, so the `.rdata` section will look something like this: `PanditJI\0SuhanaMausam\0` followed by some startup stuff.

When you take the pointer of the second string, your pointer points into that `.rdata` section: It points to the "S" of "SuhanaMausam". In your third `printf` you subtract 9 bytes from that pointer. Now if you look back to the stuff that is placed in the `.rdata` section, you will notice, that 9 bytes/characters infront of that "S" is the beginning of your first literal. The resulting pointer will therefor point to the "P" of "PanditJI".

This is why, in your lucky case, you will end up printing the first String twice.

---

Now two points I want to add as well:

- `printf` will print the stuff you pointed at until it reaches a nul character `\0`
- You can check all the stuff I wrote by using objdump on your executable: `objdump -s -j .rdata [YourExecutableName]`